# NSJSONSerialization to plain old object?

Tags: json, objective-c, json-deserialization, nsjsonserialization

A lot of modern programming languages have JSON libraries that support encoding and decoding json to/from "plain old objects" - i.e. instances of classes that primarily just have data properties (properties can either be types that can be trivially de/encoded or other plain old objects). Examples include Google's GSON, golang's `encoding/json` and others.

Is there something similar to Objective-C?

I know that it is possible to enumerate properties for Objective-C classes, and it seems reasonable that someone would have used that capability to create a JSON "bean mapper", but Google searching yielded no results for me, except [this blog post on Apple's Swift website](https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=37) showing how to manually deserialize JSON to "model objects" and why they think that doing this automatically (DRYing the code) is a bad idea (*).

<sub>*) The reasoning is basically, that not needing to write a lot of boilerplate (their sample implementation is 36 LoC to parse 3 properties) is not a significant improvement and building a couple of optional callbacks to allow data validation is hard. I obviously disagree with all of this.</sub>

Comment: Not sure if this is what you are asking, but you can paste your json here: https://app.quicktype.io and get the corresponding code in almost any language you want, including Objective-C.

Comment: Not really what I was going for - I'm looking for something that is more like "define your classes then call a library function" rather then "generate full code mapper", but it looks like the QT generator for Objective-C basically wraps `NSObject::setValuesForKeysWithDictionary` and `NSObject::dictionaryWithValuesForKeys` - which I wasn't aware of and apparently is the missing piece to just boilerplate-hell of `NSData` -> `NSJSONSerialization` -> `setValuesForKeysWithDictionary`. So that is kind of an answer.

Comment: @koen , I'm a bit hazy, though, on what happens if the JSON defines fields for which there aren't any properties - `setValue:forKey:` is mum on what happens in that case, but being resilient to the caller missing fields or providing extra fields is a requirement.

Comment: The main issue with Quicktype is that the resulting code is very brittle - it can't handle nullable values well and crashes badly when receiving unexpected JSON structures, instead of failing gracefully and leaving default values where appropriate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my solution, which is not based on a library - as I couldn't find any - but instead using the Foundation and Objective-C runtime methods - as discussed in the comments above:

```objectivec
#import <objc/runtime.h>

NSArray<NSString*>* classPropertyList(id instance) {
    NSMutableArray* propList = [NSMutableArray array];
    unsigned int numProps = 0;
    objc_property_t* props = class_copyPropertyList(object_getClass(instance), &numProps);
    for (int i = 0; i < numProps; i++)
        [propList addObject:[NSString stringWithUTF8String:property_getName(props[i])]];
    free(props);
    return propList;
}

NSString* typeOfProperty(Class clazz, NSString* propertyName) {
    objc_property_t prop = class_getProperty(clazz, [propertyName UTF8String]);
    NSArray<NSString*>* propAttrs = [[NSString stringWithUTF8String:property_getAttributes(prop)] componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
    if ([(propAttrs[0]) hasPrefix:@"T@\""])
        return [propAttrs[0] componentsSeparatedByString:@"\""][1];
    return nil;
}

@implementation JSONMarshallable

- (NSData*)toJSON {
    return [self toJSON:self withNullValues:YES];
}

- (NSString*)toJSONString {
    return [self toJSONString:self withNullValues:YES];
}

- (NSData*)toJSON:_ withNullValues:(bool)nullables {
    NSError* error;
    NSDictionary* dic = [self toDictionary:self withNullValues:nullables];
    NSData* json = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:dic options:0 error:&error];
    if (!json) {
        NSLog(@"Error encoding DeviceConfigurationRequest: %@", error);
        return nil;
    }
    return json;
}

- (NSString*) toJSONString:_ withNullValues:(bool)nullables {
    NSData* json = [self toJSON:self withNullValues:nullables];
    return [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:[json bytes] length:[json length] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
}

- (NSDictionary*)toDictionary:_ withNullValues:(bool)nullables {
    NSMutableDictionary* dic = [NSMutableDictionary new];
    for (id propName in classPropertyList(self)) {
        id val = [self valueForKey:propName];
        if (!nullables && (val == nil || val == NSNull.null))
            continue;
        if ([val respondsToSelector:@selector(toDictionary:withNullValues:)])
            val = [val toDictionary:val withNullValues:nullables];
        [dic setObject:(val == nil ? NSNull.null : val) forKey:propName];
    }
    return dic;
}

- (instancetype)initWithJSONString:(NSString*)json {
    return [self initWithJSON:[json dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
}

- (instancetype)initWithJSON:(NSData*)json {
    NSError* error;
    if (json == nil)
        return nil;
    NSDictionary* dataValues = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:json options:0 error:&error];
    if (!dataValues) {
        NSLog(@"Error parsing invalid JSON for %@: %@", NSStringFromClass(object_getClass(self)), error);
        return nil;
    }
    return [self initWithDictionary:dataValues];
}

- (instancetype)initWithDictionary:(NSDictionary*)dataValues {
    if (dataValues == nil)
        return nil;
    if (self = [super init])
        for (id key in dataValues) {
            id val = [dataValues objectForKey:key];
            if (![self respondsToSelector:NSSelectorFromString(key)])
                continue;
            NSString* typeName = typeOfProperty([self class], key);
            if ([val isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]]) { // translate NSNull values to something useful, if we can
                if (typeName == nil)
                    continue; // don't try to set nil to non-pointer fields
                val = nil;
            } else if ([val isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]] && typeName != nil)
                val = [[NSClassFromString(typeName) alloc] initWithDictionary:val];
            [self setValue:val forKey:key];
        }
    return self;
}

@end
```

It is then easy to create custom model objects by inheriting from `JSONMarshallable`, like so:

`model.h`:

```objectivec
#import "JSONMarshallable.h"

@interface MyModel : JSONMarshallable

@property NSString* stringValue;
@property NSNumber* numericValue;
@property bool boolValue;

@end
```

`model.m`:

```objectivec
@implementation MyModel
@end
```

`SomeThingElse.m`:

```objectivec
// ...

NSData* someJson;
MyModel* obj = [[MyModel alloc] initWithJSON:someJson];
NSString* jsonObj = [obj toJSONString:nil withNullValues:NO];
```

Critics are welcome! (I'm not very good at Objective C and probably made a lot of faux pas )

Issues:

- I can handle nullable numbers with `NSNumber*` (though C primitives work fine for non-nullable numbers), but I don't know how to represent nullable booleans - i.e. a field that is optional and not encoded when using `withNullValues:NO`.
- <strike>Sending fields for which there are no properties (for example, the server I work with sends values in both snake-case and underscrore-case to make it easy to parse) throws exception.</strike> (solved by using `respondsToSelector:` and `setValue:` instead of `setValuesForKeysWithDictionary:`).
- <strike>Trying to set `nil` values to primitive-typed fields causes exceptions.</strike> (solved by checking for property type and `NSNull`).
- <strike>Doesn't work at all for nesting objects - i.e. a custom model object with properties that are also custom model objects.</strike> (solved by checking for property types and recursing encoding/decoding).
- Probably doesn't handle arrays well - I have yet to need those in my software, so I haven't implemented proper support (though I verified that encoding simple string arrays works well).